# getGetFeatureInfo with time parameter returns value of old layer

Tags: geoserver, time, getfeatureinfo

I have a problem when I try to get a value from my group of layers.

I have some NetCDFs in geoserver that update every 6 hours.

In my code, I get the data from them with **getGetFeatureInfoUrl**. I use the parameter **time** to specify which value I want.

http://server/geoserver/trafikoa/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=trafikoa%3Aval_met&tiled=false&STYLES=&LAYERS=trafikoa%3Aval_met&tilesOrigin=-11.997193701565266%2C35.905838049948215&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fjavascript&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=117&Y=65&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&BBOX=-303302.12823557854%2C5283327.395071384%2C-298410.1584253273%2C5288219.364881635&**time=2017-02-17T00:00:00.000Z**

The first time I get the value, it returns OK, but when I update the NetCDF, it returns the value from 06:00:00 and not 00:00:00.

I think, somehow it's cached or something because if I remove the layer from geoserver and create again, it works fine.

How do I have to set up Geoserver?

Answer (score 1):

NetCDF files are associated with a index file containing information about available times and the like in a sidecar directory. I believe you should be remove that, and then hit "reset" in the GeoServer UI status panel (or do the equivalent with the REST API)

Comment: It worked, thanks! I made a code in php and used REALOAD of the Rest Api

Answer (score 0):

You should set time zone before doing that.

```
-Duser.timezone=GMT
```

See [this](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html) link.